# rails 2.3.5 - bug makes ActiveRecord::Base.configurations false. How do I track it down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've been updating my user test server and now suddenly I got an error every time I invoke rake with anything database-related.

Sample error:

```
rake db:drop RAILS_ENV='production' --trace

rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/databases.rake:96
```

Here's line 96 of that `databases.rake`:

```
config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[RAILS_ENV || 'development']
```

So it seems that Base.configurations is ´false´ instead of being an array.

I've been fighting this for a couple hours now but I could not find anything on my source.

Google didn't provide any useful hints.

Could anyone point out any obvious reasons why this member is false?

Comment: I don't know ... you mixed up rails 2.3.8 and 2.3.5 (as in the path)?

Comment: Have you checked your database.yml? Does the database actually exist?

Comment: @giraff, I had both versions installed, but this app is using 2.3.5. Thanks for pointing that out, I've fixed my question

Comment: What version of ruby are you using? What does your `database.yml` file look like?

Comment: @Karl: Now I feel stupid. I had kept a nano session opened so I was "seeing" the file - but the copy on the disk was somehow empty.
Saving the file solved the issue. Feel free to put your comment on an answer and I'll gladly accept it. BaroqueBobcat, thanks for your help, too, but Karl was there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my database.yml was missing.